# Google Chrome extensions update settings or Preferences file?

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, bookmarks

I found the brower whether display bookmarks bar by Settings in the option
"Always show the bookmarks bar", it is relative **"...Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences**" file:

```
{
   ......
   "bookmark_bar": {
      "show_on_all_tabs": false
   },
   ......
}
```

How can I control the "bookmarks bar" option by API or the file?

Answer (score 1):

I found that Google could not support the relative API by Google search.